# Customize login cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a form like this:

email
[input]

password
[input]

Login-Button

I want to eliminate the "email" and "password" text and put them inside the inputs like placeholder and also change the "login" text to "LOGIN".

This is my login ctp.

```
<fieldset style="background:#F44336">
    <?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <?= $this->Form->input('email') ?>
    <?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
    <?= $this->Form->button('Login') ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>

    <div class="forgot">
        <p><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing and vague.

But I believe you are asking you dont want the value or words "Email" and "Password" to be next to the input but rather inside the input textbox?

If so, you can add HTML code inside the HTML form

`<input type="email" name="email_form" placeholder="Email">`

Keep in mind that is HTML 5.

In HTML 4, the traditional way would to be adding an attribute to the HTML form to email or password as `value="Email..."`

Comment: it works but when i try to login the "email" or "password" is wrong

Comment: my bad, just change name="email_form" to name="email"

Answer (score 0):

Above code is correct but you should use helpers.

So a better way to achieve the same task with Html helpers is:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => false)); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => false)); ?>
```

It's a suggestion to make your code better which we all should focus on.